# Delete from row to row in phpadmin

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with many rows and I want want to delete from row to row but I do know the right comand.

I know that code for deleting just single row:

```
DELETE FROM `ps_econt_order` WHERE `ps_econt_order`.`econt_order_id` = 108500;
```

Also that I am using that code:

```
DELETE FROM `ps_econt_order` WHERE `ps_econt_order` IN (500,501,504,503);
```

BUT I would want to delete all rows from 505 to 108500 just with single command.

Answer (score 2):

if the rows are in ordered sequence you could use between

```
DELETE FROM ps_econt_order 
WHERE econt_order_id between 500 and 108500
```